# reloadTable after animated row deletion

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a table view with cells that can be deleted.  When a cell is deleted, I would like to display a deletion animation such as `UITableViewRowAnimationFade`.  The problem is that my table view's cells have alternating background colors, so I need to `-reloadData` after the animation completes to fix the colors of all cells below the deleted cell.

So, incase you haven't read this far, I need a way to run some code after a table view animation is complete.  I am currently using `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` and hardcoding an approximation of the animation delay.  This method works, but there must be a better way to do it:

```
NSIndexPath * path = [listTable indexPathForCell:deletingCell];
NSArray * indexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:path];
[listTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[listTable performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.35];
```

In this case I am assuming that `UITableViewRowAnimationFade` will take less than 0.35 seconds to complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use NSTimer with the same delay (although unneeded, -performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: works fine).

Another option would be to loop through the cells after `deletingCell` (`path`) and redraw them, or add the index paths to an array and call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` as shown below. Then you could also use the `UITableViewRowAnimationFade`

```
- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured there must be a good way to do this, and there is.